# error flutter clean - windows-x64/font-subset tool download failed

Tags: android-studio-3.6.1

I can't use anymore flutter clean or doctor in command line in Android Studio 3.6.1.
When I try I have this message :

> Downloading windows-x64/font-subset tools...
>   Download failed.
>   URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/windows-x64/font-subset.zip
>   Error: 404 Not Found

I try to use gradlew clean. I had exactly the same message.

By the way flutter structure is empty when I open a flutter file and I don't have any completion or shortcut to go to functions (message: cannot find declaration to go to).

Do you have any clue to why it's happen and how to fix it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. 
I remove flutter. 
I reinstall it and it's worked now.
If someone now why that's happen I am interested.

Answer (score 0):

That's happened for some network issue, your network can not access the server.
**More Details:** https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48030
Hope you will find your all answers and solutions.